# How to store nrow information from multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have 36 dataframes, labeled as
`IALPlms3,IALPsts3,IALPlmns3,IALPstns3`,
`IALPlms4,IALPsts4,IALPlmns4,IALPstns4`,
`IALPlms5,IALPsts5,IALPlmns5,IALPstns5`,
`...`
`IALPlms11,IALPsts11,IALPlmns11,IALPstns11`. So that there could be 4 different types of strings in the label (i.e., `IALPlms`,`IALPsts`,`IALPlmns`,`IALPstns`), but 9 different numbers (from 3 to 11).

I would like to store the number of rows of each dataframe in a new dataframe.
I have created the new dataframe:

```
tableROWS <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 9)), c("IALPlms","IALPsts","IALPlmns","IALPstns"))
row.names(tableROWS) <- c("table3","table4","table5","table6","table7","table8","table9","table10","table11")
```

Now I would like to create a loop, such that for each dataframe, I store the number of rows. I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
for(i in 3:11) {
  for (j in 1:9) {
    tableROWS[j,1] = nrow(IALPlms(i))
    tableROWS[j,2] = nrow(IALPsts(i))
    tableROWS[j,3] = nrow(IALPlmns(i))
    tableROWS[j,4] = nrow(IALPstns(i))   
  }

}
```

I would like to obtain something like:

```
        IALPlms IALPsts IALPlmns    IALPstns
table3  #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table4  #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table5  #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table6  #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table7  #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table8  #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table9  #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table10 #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
table11 #nrow   #nrow   #nrow       #nrow
```

I have also tried to use within the loop for example:

```
    labelA <- paste("IALPlms",(i) )
    labelA <-gsub(" ","",labelA)
```

and then to use `nrow(labelA)`, but it doesn't recognise it as the existing dataframe, it assumes it is just a string.

Comment: You can have a vectorized solution for this that will be faster than a loop, but please provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get`-function after constructing the strings for the variable names to fetch your object where the variable name is a string literal.
Try for example:

```
var1 <- 1:2
var2 <- 5:6

get("var1")  #== var1
#[1] 1 2

var.name <- "var2"
get(var.name)
#[1] 5 6
```

So, something like this should work:

```
tableROWS <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 9)), c("IALPlms","IALPsts","IALPlmns","IALPstns"))
row.names(tableROWS) <- c("table3","table4","table5","table6","table7","table8","table9","table10","table11")
for(i in 3:11) {
  tableROWS[i-2,1] <- nrow(get(paste0("IALPlms", i)))
  tableROWS[i-2,2] <- nrow(get(paste0("IALPsts", i)))
  tableROWS[i-2,3] <- nrow(get(paste0("IALPlmns", i)))
  tableROWS[i-2,4] <- nrow(get(paste0("IALPstns", i)) )  
}
```

However, I'm not sure what the purpose of your `j`-loop above is, you only need to loop over the table-suffixes.

More tightly written, you could do:

```
for(i in 3:11) {
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(tableROWS))) {
    tableROWS[i-2, 1] <- nrow(get(paste0(names(tableROWS)[j], i)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly!